# Aggregate function on subquery

Tags: sql-server, optimization, query, subquery

I have got a SALES table that has 4 document types, and they are created with reference to each other in the following order:

> Offer -> Order -> Delivery -> Invoice.

For each new row their REFDOCTYPE and REFDOCNUM column is updated according to the previous document type and number. I want counts of offers with different sub-queries grouped by customers.

1. First column counts Offers that has become an invoice in the end.
2. Second column counts offers that have a sales order but didn't end up being an invoice.
3. Last column counts offers that are passive (no document referenced them).

This query gives the following error 3 times:

> "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."

How can I write it differently ? I tried making them a `left join` but it didn't work. Here is the query:

```
    SELECT 
Q.CUSTOMER,
SUM(CASE WHEN EXISTS
(SELECT COMPANY FROM SALES O WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE O.COMPANY = Q.COMPANY AND O.REFDOCTYPE = Q.DOCTYPE AND O.REFDOCNUM = Q.DOCNUM AND O.DOCTYPE = 'ORDER' AND O.ISDELETED = 0 AND EXISTS
 (SELECT COMPANY FROM SALES D WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE AND D.COMPANY = O.COMPANY AND D.REFDOCTYPE = O.DOCTYPE AND D.REFDOCNUM = O.DOCNUM AND D.DOCTYPE = 'DELIVERY' AND D.ISDELETED = 0 AND EXISTS
  (SELECT COMPANY FROM SALES I WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE AND I.COMPANY = D.COMPANY AND I.REFDOCTYPE = D.DOCTYPE AND I.REFDOCNUM = D.DOCNUM AND I.DOCTYPE = 'INVOICE' AND D.ISDELETED = 0))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HasInvoice,

  SUM (CASE WHEN EXISTS
(SELECT COMPANY FROM SALES O WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE O.COMPANY = Q.COMPANY AND O.REFDOCTYPE = Q.DOCTYPE AND O.REFDOCNUM = Q.DOCNUM AND O.DOCTYPE = 'ORDER' AND O.ISDELETED = 0 AND NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT COMPANY FROM SALES D WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE AND D.COMPANY = O.COMPANY AND D.REFDOCTYPE = O.DOCTYPE AND D.REFDOCNUM = O.DOCNUM AND D.DOCTYPE = 'DELIVERY' AND D.ISDELETED = 0)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OrderWithoutInvoice,

   SUM (CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS
(SELECT COMPANY FROM SALES O WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE O.COMPANY = Q.COMPANY AND O.REFDOCTYPE = Q.DOCTYPE AND O.REFDOCNUM = Q.DOCNUM AND O.DOCTYPE = 'ORDER' AND O.ISDELETED = 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NoOrder

FROM SALES Q WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE Q.DOCTYPE = 'OFFER'
  AND Q.ISDELETED = 0
  AND Q.DOCDATE > '2019-09-01'
  GROUP BY Q.CUSTOMER
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, that is limitation. However, you probably want try as follows:

```
SELECT  Q.CUSTOMER,
        COUNT (DISTINCT CASE WHEN O.REFDOCNUM is not null and D.REFDOCNUM is not null and D.REFDOCNUM is not null
                    THEN S.DOCNUM END
              ) AS HasInvoice,

        COUNT (DISTINCT CASE WHEN O.REFDOCNUM is not null and D.REFDOCNUM is null
                    THEN S.DOCNUM END
              ) AS OrderWithoutInvoice

        COUNT (Distinct S.DOCNUM) as TotalOffers

FROM SALES S WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT * 
         FROM   SALES O WITH (NOLOCK) 
         WHERE  O.DOCTYPE = 'ORDER' AND O.ISDELETED = 0 
         ) AS O ON S.COMPANY = O.COMPANY AND S.REFDOCTYPE = O.DOCTYPE AND S.DOCNUM = O.REFDOCNUM

    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT * 
         FROM   SALES WITH (NOLOCK) 
         WHERE  DOCTYPE = 'INVOICE' AND ISDELETED = 0 
         ) AS I ON S.COMPANY = I.COMPANY AND S.REFDOCTYPE = I.DOCTYPE AND S.DOCNUM = I.REFDOCNUM

    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT * 
         FROM   SALES WITH (NOLOCK) 
         WHERE  DOCTYPE = 'DELIVERY' AND ISDELETED = 0 
         ) AS D ON S.COMPANY = D.COMPANY AND S.REFDOCTYPE = D.DOCTYPE AND S.DOCNUM = D.REFDOCNUM

WHERE Q.DOCTYPE = 'OFFER' AND Q.ISDELETED = 0 AND Q.DOCDATE > '2019-09-01'
GROUP BY Q.CUSTOMER
```